# How to split current item (string) in Azure Application Insights - Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I'm doing a custom dashboard in Azure Insights, and I'd like to display Exceptions type. In order to do so, I need to split an `outerMessage` column. I know that there is a [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/splitfunction) function, but I don't know how to use it with current `item`. Any idea how to use split?

```
exceptions
| project outerMessage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it! It was quite intuitive, current item is the name of the column. In my case it was `outerMessage`. I used new line `"\n"` as my delimiter.

```
exceptions
| project split(outerMessage, "\n")
```

Comment: Here is [the sql cheatsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet) that compares Kusto wit SQL. Can come handy :)